# Not able to send the null value for a key in FormURLEncoded Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

Request need to send like this

```
{
  "ProjectId": 1156,
  "StagingId": 2,
  "Address": "",
  "PhoneNo": "",
  "HomeMktDate": "",
  "AdditionalInfo": "",
  "FullName": "",
  "UserId": 683,
  "ScheduleDates": "",
  "ExperienceLevel": "",
  "StagingTerm": "",
  "Location": "",
  "Profession": ""
}
```

Using Retrofit2 , GsonConvertFactory

```
 public static Retrofit getClient_token() {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setLenient().serializeNulls();

        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

        initOkHttp_token();

        if (retrofit1 == null) {
            retrofit1 = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
                    .client(okHttpClient1)
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit1;
    }
```

Creating the Request

```
 Comman.getApiToken().SaveProjectInfo(projectId,
                    stagingId,
                    selectedDate,
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "2020-09-14T13:00:13.426Z",
                    "",
                    "",
                    UserId,
                    "",
                    "",
                    selectedData)
                    .enqueue(new Callback<SavedDataModal>() {
```

Query is updated with more code snippets, please let me know

While hitting the api, it removed the empty string values. I need to send the key with empty string or as null.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code a bit as below -

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder(); 
gsonBuilder.setLenient().serializeNulls();

Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks @priyanka for quick answer, but it is not working either. :(. Any other suggestion to achieve this

Comment: I am using in same way , its working for me. Can you share your code snippet? exactly how and where you are using this?